# Unable to access sub-domain using .htaccess in my Laravel5.8 site on cpanel shared hosting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain, laravel-5.8

I got a `Laravel 5.8` site hosted on shared hosting. I want to access my `subdomain` using `.htaccess` file but I'm unable to figure out how to make it work.

**My directory structure looks like this:**

```
public_html/
           cdn/ (subdomain directory)
              index.php
           public/ (assets and index.php file reside here)
                 css/
                 js/
                 images/
                 fonts/
                 index.php (loads laravel site) 

           .htaccess (responsible to load index.php from the public directory)
```

So, basically, right now, if I try to access `cdn` directory like this `http://example.com/cdn`, that takes me to `http://example.com/public/cdn` and if I try `http://cdn.example.com`, the browser gives me the error message that **This site can’t be reached**.

I tried [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-2-projects-shared-host-subdomain-htaccess?page=0#reply=143571) but it does not work.

```
   RewriteEngine On


   # Handling subdomain
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?cdn.example.com$
   ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ cdn/$1 [L]

   # Loads index.php located inside laravel's public directory
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
   ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

When I try to access, `http://cdn.example.com`, the browser gives me the error message that **This site can’t be reached**.

It supposed to load `index.php` file located inside `cdn` directory.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: “This site can’t be reached” usually means the browser could not resolve the host name via the DNS system. You of course have to make `cdn.example.com` resolve to your server’s IP address first of all, before your server can redirect anyone anywhere else.

Comment: Actually, I got another site hosted on the same server and that has the folder name like this in `public_html/example2.com()`. I set up a subdomain for this and it worked instantly. There was no need to resolve my IP address. The problem I'm facing with Laravel directory structure. On `public_html`, there is an `.htaccess` file which enforces everything to `public_html/public`. I'm assuming, the problem is with the `.htaccess` located on the root directory.

Comment: _“I set up a subdomain for this and it worked instantly”_ - that doesn’t necessarily mean anything - that other domain might have a DNS wildcard entry that automatically handles this. Do a ping for `cdn.example.com` on your client machine, and you will see whether it can be resolved via the DNS, or not.

Comment: No. Both domains have the same DNS settings. I just checked.